# Memory allocation oddity with certain special symbols

Tags: vba, excel, memory-management

In the process of creating a VBA program in Excel, I came across a limitation that doesn't seem to be documented anywhere (that I have found so far).

The cell contents limit is documented at 0-32767 characters, however for the characters "@", "-", "+" and "=" I cannot write a VBA script to add these characters to a cell beyond 8192 characters, which is oddly enough 1/4 of 32768.

In the process of debugging, I created a separate script to attempt this to avoid any other issues my program presented regarding memory allocation.

```
Function Insert()

    For i = 1 To 8199
        Range("J13") = Range("J13") & "@"
    Next

End Function
```

The program concatenates "@" to the cell up to (and including) 8192 and then halts with a "runtime error 7 Out of Memory" error. It does not seem to be a cell limitation as I can manually enter more symbols to the cell once the program has halted.

I have also tried manually entering about 1000 symbols before I start the program, but it still halts at 8192.

This issue does not occur when using any special character standard on a full size standard US-format keyboard (other than the 4 I have listed).

I assumed that this might be because of character encoding and the corresponding memory requirements of these characters but I cannot find any information that indicates the memory requirements for these four symbols are different than any of the other standard symbols on my keyboard.

Does any one have any insight on why this might be happening, and a potential workaround?

And yes, oddly enough I do require sometimes to have a cell filled with more than 8192 characters of these types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These four characters are valid as the beginning of a formula, but [Excel specifications and limits](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Excel-specifications-and-limits-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3) states:

> Length of formula contents - 8,192 characters

So `Range("J13") = String(8193, "@")` will fail (because it is being interpreted as a formula), but `Range("J13") = "x" & String(8193, "@")` will work (because it won't be interpreted as a formula).

---

A workaround would be to use `Range("J13") = "'" & String(8193, "@")` which will force the cell to be treated as text, with just 8193 `"@"` characters in it.

---

Note: I was scratching my head trying to work out **why** the `@` symbol could be used to start a formula (and just gets changed to an `=` after entering it).  I knew I had seen it being used somewhere, so I googled it and found a page that reminded me that that was how we started a formula in Lotus123.  So it has been incorporated into Excel to allow ex-Lotus123 users to continue to work in their usual way.  (That's the same reason as why `/` brings up the menus.)